# how i can pass "var status = true" from my jquery script to the js.erb file or other solutions?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a controller action that looks like this:

```
@sports = @articles.sports.paginate(page: params[:sports_page], per_page: 6)
@world =  @articles.world.paginate(page: params[:world_page], per_page: 6)
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render 'index_region' }
  format.js { render :file => "/articles/latest.js.erb" }
end
```

And both of these objects are paginated in the view at the same time.

And I want to paginate both of these objects through `ajax/js.erb`

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {
  if($('#sports').size() > 0) {
    $('.sports-pagination').hide();
    $('#load_more_photos_sports').show();
    $('#load_more_photos_sports').on('click', function() {
      var urlsports = $('.sports-pagination>.pagination .next_page a').attr('href');
      $.getScript(urlsports);
    });
  }
  if($('#world').size() > 0) {
    $('.world-pagination').hide();
    $('#load_more_photos_world').show();
    $('#load_more_photos_world').on('click', function() {
      var urlworld = $('.world-pagination>.pagination .next_page a').attr('href');
      $.getScript(urlworld);
    })
  }
});
```

but whichever button is clicked, I guess it has to go through the same `js.erb` file? Is that correct? Or can i somehow tell the controller to respond with different `js.erb` files depending on which button was clicked?

Or, if I can add `var status = true` and `var status = false` into the code and pass that into the js.erb file, then I can setup an `if statement` that only runs the code related to the button that was clicked.

Comment: take a look at gon to pass variables into your javascript. https://github.com/gazay/gon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by `addingClass` to the element in the jquery script and then using an `if statement` in the `js.erb` to check for that class. If there is a better way, please let me know.